# How can I find the vector equation of the line that C must follow to meet A at right angles

Tags: vectors

[image]
I need to find the vector equation of the line that C needs to follow to meet A at right angles.

I was able to find the vector equation of AD as $(1,1) + λ(3,5)$

Vector equation of the line through C will be $(9,2) + μ(x_1, y_1)$

Since these 2 lines intersect, can I say:
$1 + 3λ = 9 + x_1μ$

and $1 + 5λ = 2 + y_1μ$

But then I don't know where to go from here.

Another way I can see this is that the dot product of perpendicular lines is 0. So, $v_1$ . $v_3$ = 0

So, $(3,5).((9 + x_1μ),(2 + y_1μ)$

$0 = 3(9 + x_1) + 5(2 + y_1)$

$=> 0 = 27 + 3x_1 + 25 + 5y_1$

$=> 3x_1 + 5y_1 = -52$

And now I've confused myself again. Can someone please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You've got most of the right ideas. As $C$ is perpendicular to $AD$, that means their *direction* vectors are perpendicular, though – not $C$'s position vector with $AD$'s direction vector. So $(x_1, x_2)$ is perpendicular to $(3,5)$. Since we can choose this up to a scalar factor, let's choose $(x_1, x_2) = (-5, 3)$.

You have the right idea with the intersection of these two lines, so I'll leave you to do that part yourself.